# Open filter on range from another workbook delete rename tab save as from another workbook x20

Tags: excel, vba

I have managed put a code together. It is working, but it's not very sufficient as I would need to create a 20 macros and rename the filtered text for each macro. I have two workbooks Q4 where the code saved (Q4 - cell A1:A20 filter text & B1:B20 file name) and and AA workbook where everything happening. How  can I create it loops through the workbook Q4 and also the filter selects the range form workbook Q4?

```
Sub Delete_Rows()

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim Path As String
Dim Filename As String
Dim rng As Range
Dim lastRow As Long

Path = "C:\Users\jam_jam\Desktop\ABC\ABC1\"  'Saves file

Workbooks.Open ("C:\Users\jam_jam\Desktop\ABC\AA.xlsx")  'Opens work book
Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

lastRow = ws.Range("D" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row 
Set rng = ws.Range("D1:D" & lastRow)

'''''''' filter and delete all but header row
With rng
.AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:="<>*ABCD*" 'I would like to filter by range from workbook Q4
.Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
End With

ws.Name = ws.Range("D2")
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$N$3000").AutoFilter Field:=4
Range("M2").Select

Filename = Workbooks("Q4.xlsm").Worksheets("333").Range("E13")
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=Path & Filename & ".xlsx", FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook
ActiveWorkbook.Close

End Sub
```

Thank you for any help?

Comment: Can't get what you want to do... Add screenshots of what you have and what you want to have

Answer (score 0):

''' With rng
.AutoFilter field:=4, Criteria1:="<>*" & arr & "*" 'Filters by excel value 
.Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
End With